# Get an image to upload and display within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-uploading

Please review my [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/RE6Fu/)...

I have a file upload button, which works fine. You'll see it when you barely scroll down in the fiddle. The image uploads, but it uploads down at the bottom of the page, and I'm trying to get it to display within a div, immediately below the upload button.

**HTML**...

```
`<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /></label>
   <p>
      <strong>(Image will display below)</strong>
   </p>
      <div style="max-width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px dashed black;">
   <img id="blah" src="#" alt="Your image goes here..." />
</div>`
```

**JS**...

```
`$("input").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $("input").after(img);
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the src attribute of the image you already have within the div. The following code should do what you want.

```
`$("input").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             $('#blah').attr('src', reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);        }
});`
```

Comment: Question for you... any idea how I would add multiple images to this? Within different upload locations on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `after` which insert your image after the `input` tag and not the image.

To insert your image inside your `div` you need to have a selector on this `div` like an id:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /></label>
<p>
   <strong>(Image will display below)</strong>
</p>
<div style="max-width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px dashed black;" id="whatever">
</div>
```

And then do:

```
$('#whatever").html(img);
```

Comment: I'm considering yours too... You do realize that yours doesn't work though, right? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/tNzxu/)

Comment: Oh I forgot to test it first sorry. The solution of Adam is better anyway.